# Optimizing Numpy Operations

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, classification, logistic-regression

I am trying to train a multi-class classifier with multinomial logistic regression and gradient descent. Specifically, the model will have a trained weights matrix w with shape (C, D) where C is the number of classes and D is the number of features of each input. Also, we will have a bias vector b with dimension (C,). We have an (N, D) input matrix X, where N is the number of training inputs, and a vector y with shape (N,), where each entry in y is a number from 0 to C - 1, indicating which class the input belongs to. I have written the following code:

```
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        z = np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: v - max(v), 1, X @ w.T + b)
        probs = np.exp(z)
        denom = np.sum(probs, axis=1)
        for i in range(C):
            for j in range(N):
                if i == y[j]:
                    w[i] -= (step_size / N) * ((probs[j][i] / denom[j]) - 1) * X[j]
                    b[i] -= (step_size / N) * ((probs[j][i] / denom[j]) - 1)
                else:
                    w[i] -= (step_size / N) * (probs[j][i] / denom[j]) * X[j]
                    b[i] -= (step_size / N) * (probs[j][i] / denom[j])
```

This produces the correct weights and bias that I want, but clearly it doesn't take advantage of numpy's operations to speed things up. So I tried to speed some of it up with the following code:

```
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        z = np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: v - max(v), 1, X @ w.T + b)
        probs = np.exp(z)
        denom = np.sum(probs, axis=1)
        s = np.zeros((N, C))
        for i in range(N):
            s[i] = probs[i] / denom[i]
        for i in range(N):
            s[i][y[i]] += -1
        for c in range(C):
            grad_w = s.T[c] @ X
            w[c] += (step_size / N) * grad_w
            b[c] += (step_size / N) * sum(s.T[c])
```

I was hoping that this would produce the same results as in the previous part while being faster... and it managed to be faster, but with incorrect results.

So I have a couple of questions. First, why is my second piece of code not producing the right results, and what would be a fix for it? Second, and more importantly, how would I optimize this further? This is mainly for me to learn how to take advantage of numpy's vectorized operations.

Comment: Not that it deals with the  bigger question, but `np.apply_along_axis` is not a speed tool.  And I suspect it can be replaced with `np.max` using `axis` and possibly the `keepdims` parameters (no iteration).

Answer (score 0):

This may help with some of the iterations.

Start with a small 2d array:

```
In [251]: probs = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [252]: denom = np.sum(probs, axis=1)
In [253]: denom
Out[253]: array([ 6, 22, 38])
```

To divide a (3,4) array by a (3,), we need to make the later (3,1):

```
In [254]: probs/denom[:,None]
Out[254]: 
array([[0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ],
       [0.18181818, 0.22727273, 0.27272727, 0.31818182],
       [0.21052632, 0.23684211, 0.26315789, 0.28947368]])
```

Read, and reread, the `numpy` documentation on `broadcasting` if that doesn't make sense.

Another way to get the required 2d denom, is:

```
In [255]: denom = np.sum(probs, axis=1, keepdims=True)
In [256]: denom
Out[256]: 
array([[ 6],
       [22],
       [38]])
In [257]: probs/denom
Out[257]: 
array([[0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ],
       [0.18181818, 0.22727273, 0.27272727, 0.31818182],
       [0.21052632, 0.23684211, 0.26315789, 0.28947368]])
```

The same should work for the `max` subtraction that you use with `apply_along_axis`.  `apply...` is not a speed tool, and not superior to simple iteration.

```
In [258]: np.max(probs, axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[258]: 
array([[ 3],
       [ 7],
       [11]])
In [259]: probs - _
Out[259]: 
array([[-3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
```